# how to get 2 Ids and 1 row name

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to query 2 Ids and one of the rows name of the table from my database so that I can send the name that I query to another page. Instead I´m only able to use query 2 the Ids and not the the name that I want.
What am I doing wrong?

[My DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etj3i.png)

**Here is my code**

```
<?php
$con =@ pg_connect ("port=5432 host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=a");
if ($con==NULL){
  echo "Cannot connect to database or No Database found.";
  exit (0);
}
$sql= "select distinct(departamento) from grades where student_id='$id' order by departamento asc;";
$res = @pg_query ($con, $sql);

if ($res == NULL){
  echo "Query failed.";
  exit (0);
}
for ($i=0; $i< pg_numrows ($res);$i++){
  echo '<table style="font-size:14px;" bgcolor=white width=900px><tr>';
  $departamento=pg_result ($res, $i , "departamento");
  $curso = pg_fetch_result($res, $i, "curso");

  $sql2="select cursoid, codigo, curso, abreviacao from grades where departamento='$departamento' and student_id='$id';";
  $res2=pg_query($con, $sql2);

  echo "<tr><td colspan=10 align=center><b><b>$departamento";
  echo '<tr><td align=center style="color:green;"><b>Código<td align=center style="color:green;"><b>Curso<td align=center style="color:green;"><b>Abreviação'; 

  for ($x=0; $x< @pg_numrows ($res2);$x++){
    echo '<tr align=center bgcolor=white style="color:black;">';
    echo"<br>";
    for ($j=1; $j <pg_numfields($res2);$j++){
      echo "<td><hr><a href=scorelist.php?curso=$curso>".pg_result($res2,$x ,$j)."</a>";
    }
    $grdid=pg_result($res2,$x , 0);
    //echo "<td> <a href=editgrade.php?id=$id&grdid=$grdid>EDITAR</a>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  echo"<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with index 0:

```php
for ($j=0; $j <pg_numfields($res2);$j++)
{
      echo "<td><hr><a href=scorelist.php?curso=$curso>".pg_result($res2,$x ,$j)."</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Draz. How would I send send the curso to another page. If you see on the picture of my database there is a row called curso, I want to send that data to another page. How do I do it using select distinct method?

Comment: you can use the php statement `include` whitch  will parse the other page, or you can call the page using the url and set the curso as parameter e.g.
`mypage.php?curso=<$curso>`